# Urban runoff volume calculation

Tags: qgis, hydrology, runoff

I was wondering if someone could help me out on how to calculate runoff volume within an urban area ?

I have already produced different outputs:

- Filled DEM
- Catchment area
- Channel network
- flow direction
- junctions
- watershed basins
- drainage basin
- maximum flow path lentgh
- channel network
- upslope area

And I have also ranked the different surfaces according to an imperviousness gradient.

Now I would like to identify the area that would be the most vulnerable to a flooding. Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful so far.

I took a look over [r.sim water](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.sim.water.html) that seems to be a promising tools for that but I'm facing issues with it !

Comment: Hi, you have done a lot! but I do not see in your list the rain. Hydrology is a complete discipline, do not underlavue it. GIS is a great tool for hydologist but it cannot repleace them at all. Are you familiar with the discipline? if yes, you should define the scope a bit better, volume? annual volume or mean flow? peak flow instead? which return period? My guess is that you want to estimate a peak flow, then I suggest you to have a look to the [SWMM](https://www.epa.gov/water-research/storm-water-management-model-swmm)

Comment: There are some intersting efforts to produce the input files for SWMM in QGIS, but they are still quite complicated. I have posted some steps here with my atempts to produce them from QGIS. You coudl find them with the tag `swmm`. I read about the QGEP plugin, but I have been able to try it yet.

Comment: Hi Marco ! Thanks for your quick reply ! 
I'm not a hydrologist but I'm trying to get more proficient in such analysis. 
I was in deed trying to calculate the runoff volume for a peak flow but time is running out and I guess I would just try to identify the most vulnerable area to flooding thanks to the TWI index (SAGA).

Many thanks again for your answer, 

Romain